# Javascript remove object from property

Tags: javascript

If you have an object attached to a property like so :

```
obj = {};
obj.prop = {name:'test'};
```

Is there a way, similar to using `array.splice`, to remove the object from that property, and return it so it can be attached to another object?

Comment: @Tushar That returns a bool.

Comment: So, @frankastin, did either of the answers answer your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can:

```js
var obj = {};
obj.prop = { name: 'test' };

var newObj = { prop: obj.prop} ; // Copy prop to a new object
delete obj.prop;                // delete `prop` on the old object.

document.body.textContent = 'newObj: ' + JSON.stringify(newObj);
```

[`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) throws an error in strict mode if the property is an own non-configurable property (returns false in non-strict). It returns `true` in all other cases.

So, while there technically isn't a function like `pop` or `splice` that returns the removed property, it's trivial to work around that.

Answer (score 0):

To delete/return a property from an object in one swoop, I think you need your own function for this. Something like:

```js
function removeValue(obj, property) {
  var prop = obj[property];
  delete obj[property];
  return prop;
}
```

Comment: The property argument would need to be the string representation of the object's property.